# How to put JSON response to a tableview

Tags: arrays, json, swift, uitableview, rx-swift

I have a model Users and in that model

```
    static func getUsers() -> Single<[Users]> {
    let path = API.Path.users.details
    let params: [String: Any] = [
        "utcOffset": TimeZone.current.utcOffset
    ]

    return API.requestMany(path: path, method: .get, parameters: params)
    }
```

i declare it like this

```
    let sus = [Users]()
```

And in my cellForRowAt i have this

```
        Users
        .getUsers()
        .do(onError: { [weak self] error in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        })
        .do(onSuccess: { [weak self] userNames in
            print(userNames)
            cell.name.text = userNames[indexPath.row].name
        })
        .subscribe()
        .disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
```

That code is not being called so my tableview is empty but when i tried putting it in **ViewDidLoad** its being called and triggering my print statement **print(userNames)**

Comment: i'm properly mapping the array i can see it in the console.

Comment: Don't call `getUsers()` etc inside `cellForRow`. Instead, make sure your data is ready to go before displaying your table. Once your data is ready, call `tableView.reloadData()`.

Comment: @koen Where should i call the getUsers() i'm practicing MVVM.

Comment: Probably inside `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: @koen i tried but still not showing up. is it possible to call in inside the tableviewCell ?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with MMVM and RX-Swift, so hopefully someone else can chine in with better advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't being called because nothing is calling the function that you put the code in. It works in `viewDidLoad` because that function is being called.

Based on your description I would expect code that looks like this in your viewDidLoad()

```
    Users.getUsers()
        .asObservable()
        .bind(to: tableView.rx.items) { tableView, index, user in
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: IndexPath(index: index)) as! MyTableViewCell
            cell.configure(for: user)
            return cell
        }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Based on your comments, I've come to understand that you only want to use Rx for your network calls. In that case, the solution should look like this:

```
final class ExampleViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    private var users: [User] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        _ = User.getUsers()
            .subscribe(
                onSuccess: { [weak self] in
                    self?.users = $0
                    self?.tableView.reloadData()
                },
                onError: { error in
                    print("handle network error here")
                }
            )
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 44
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        users.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
        cell.configure(for: users[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}

final class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    func configure(for user: User) { 
        print("configure your cell here")
    }

}

struct User {
    static func getUsers() -> Single<[User]> { fatalError("Implement me") }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to have an API call inside the tableviewCell?

Comment: Sure it is, but it doesn't make sense for the api call that generates the data which feeds the table view inside just one of its cells.

Comment: yes that makes sense. how can i do the rendering of data inside cellForRowAt i dont want to remove the `extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {...}` for easy setup.

Comment: I strongly disagree with your "easy setup" comment, but I answered the question anyway.

Comment: i'm having an error in this one `.bind(to: tableView.rx.items(dataSource: self))` the error was `Cannot invoke 'items' with an argument list of type '(dataSource: ViewController)'`

Comment: The code I posted does not have that error. What is different between what you have and what I posted?

Comment: I used your first solution. but i'm having a problem setting the `heightForRowAt` i can't make my cell bigger.

Comment: Okay, I see that you only want to use Rx for network calls. I have updated my answer with that in mind.

Comment: yes. so i'm using this `tableView.rx.setDelegate(self).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)` and setting the delegate method but it some weird way i'ts not working.

Comment: yes i only want the Rx for network calls with the code i'm getting an error on `.subscribe` which is `Expression type 'Disposable' is ambiguous without more context` i tried putting `.disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)` at the end of it but it didnt work.

Comment: The code I posted above compiles and runs. What did you do different?

Comment: because i'm using `Single<[Users]>` and you are using `Observable<[Users]>` for my request.

Comment: now it gives me this `Expression type 'Disposable' is ambiguous without more context` on the `.subscribe`  i'm sorry this is taking so long.

Comment: i figured it out already. thank you for helping me. i'll accept this answer. :)